# $\Delta T$, temperature units. How to use fahrenheit in this formula

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, unit-conversion

To calculate the power in a fluid with a flow, the following formula is applied:

$$P = \Delta T \rho c_p \times flow$$

$\Delta T$ can be entered as both Kelvin and Celsius. But what if I want to use Fahrenheit? Is there any formula for this?

Reason is I'm making a web application that calculate some stuff. I have full unit support. I live in Europe so we always use Celsius or Kelvin. But, are americans using fahrenheit for calculations in general? If not, then maybe I can skip it all together.

Comment: Multiply by 5/9

Comment: Thx for answear! Haven't added the feature yet in my app but it will be available in next version. Here's my app btw, http://sizepipe.com/.

Comment: Looks cool! Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the conversion from Celsius to Fahrenheit is given by:

$$T_F=T_C\cdot 1.8+32$$

Then,

$\Delta T_F=T_{F_2}-T_{F_1}=T_{C_2}\cdot1.8 +32 -T_{C_1}\cdot1.8-32 = \Delta T_C\cdot1.8 $

Or, to be used in that case,

$$\Delta T_C = \frac{\Delta T_F}{1.8}$$

So the formula becomes

$$P =\frac{\Delta T_F}{1.8} \rho c_p \times flow$$